# How to write a Spring JPA repository method name to activate the Distinct clause in Couchbase?

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

Working on a Java application that uses Spring Data Couchbase 2.2.0.RELEASE...

Starting with a list of JSON objects that represent `Book` objects:

```
[
    {id: 123, title: "Abc", category: "A"},
    {id: 456, title: "Efg", category: "B"},
    {id: 789, title: "Abc", category: "A"}
]
```

The array of `Book` objects are inserted into Couchbase.  Later, the application would like get a list of distinct book titles back based on a category filter.   Following some of the Spring documentation, I've arrived at this method name in the `BookRepository` interface:

```
List<Book> findDistinctTitleByCategory(String category);
```

However, the query that is created by Spring does not contain the `Distinct` clause for title.  Here's is the final query that Spring sends to the CB cluster where bucket name here is `default`:

```
Executing N1QL query: {"statement":"SELECT META(`default`).id AS _ID, META(`default`).cas AS _CAS, `default`.* FROM `default` WHERE (`category` = \"A\")","scan_consistency":"not_bounded"}
```

Am I writing the method name wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDC currently does not support query derivation for distinct. I have created a ticket for enhancement [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH-307). In the meantime, you can work around by directly using `@Query` instead of n1ql.selectEntity, provide the select part.

If you are fetching only the title, SDC supports [projections](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#_dto_projections).

```
interface OnlyTitle {
    String getTitle(); 
}

@Query(...)
OnlyTitle findDistinctTitleByCategory(String category);
```

Comment: Thank you for opening up a ticket.